# Data sensitivity classification in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2019

Is there any way in SQL Server 2019 to physically partition data by [*Data Sensitivity Classification*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-data-discovery-and-classification) and thereby allow different security mechanisms to be used with different sensitivities?

[New Command in SQL Server 2019 `ADD SENSITIVITY CLASSIFICATION`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5715/new-command-in-sql-server-2019-add-sensitivity-classification/)

Answer (score 4):

Sensitivity classification is a feature of SSMS rather than SQL Server.

Based on SSMS suggestions in Data Sensitivity & Classification Wizard you might decide to change your data model.

Beside, Aron's article, there is mine too.

So, check [Data Discovery & Classification in SQL Server](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/data-discovery-classification-sql-server-darko-martinovic/) which might help you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-sensitivity-classification-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 would suggest that data classification is now native to sqlserver.  My question remains - is it possible to partition based on the levels?

Comment: Thank you for the link @Paul but I don't understand how Darko Martinovic was able to extract the KeyWord list on which SSMS bases the Data Discovery & Classification